# How to get the IP address of smtp server in java mail?

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I am connecting to smtp mail cluster to send email. I am using java mail . I want the smtp server IP which is actually sending email not the mail cluster (load balancer) ip. How to get that in java mail ? I really appreciate  any help or pointer.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail isn't going to help you.  Depending on how the load balancer works, there may be no way to get that information.  Why do you need it?  Isn't it sufficient to talk to the load balancer IP?

Comment: Thanks Bill for you response. We need ip of the actual machine which is processing our mail, not ip of load balancer. In our mail cluster, only few set of servers having issue (connection timeout while reading response / too much load to that server) . We need those servers ips to reach out to our mail server team to resolve the issue.

Comment: You might be able to find this information in the Received headers of messages sent through your servers.  Of course, if you need the IP because the server isn't responding, that's not going to help you.